# ¿Que hacen estos comandos? No los entiendo muy bien

Tags: linux, ubuntu, línea-de-comandos

Tengo unas comanda que básicamente no las entiendo del todo bien y quisiera que alguien con conocimiento de SO linux me ayudara.

```
find -name "*mp3*" -exec mv {} $HOME \
```

Se que find esta realizando una busque en todos los directorios donde los archivos o directorios que contengan en su nombre mp3 -exec(Creo que sea ejecutable) mv (para mover) {} (No la entiendo muy bien pero es para indicar un patrón) $HOME (hace referencia al directorio /home/) (No tengo idea).

```
find $HOME -name "*.txt" | tr -d " "
```

Parecido al anterior pero con la agregación de tr(no lo entiendo muy bien pero entiendo que lo que pongamos en el argumento 1 "" se remplazara por el argumento 2 "" ej: tr "ax" "bz" remplaza las ax por bz) -d y que el nombre del archivo o directorio termine en .txt

no se si no se especifica en la comanda find d(directorio) o f(fichero) escoge por defecto uno de los dos?

Mi gran duda es que no entiendo muy bien lo que hacen. Si me pudieran ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Tampoco soy un experto, pero al menos en el primer comando, lo que hace exec es ejecutar lo que está delante de él por cada resultado de find. como hacer un foreach en algún lenguaje de programación.
----
mv  = comando para mover archivos (cortar y pegar) ---
{} = es el comdodín  que hace referencia al archivo encontrado ---
$HOME = vendría siendo la ruta de destino, donde se moverá el archivo, $HOME hace referencia a la carpeta /home/<usuario> ---
\ = es un caracter de escape, para evitar que se siga propagando el comando con las siguientes instrucciones:

Comment: Puedes obtener más información del comando find ejecutando:
man finde

Comment: La solución la pude encontrar en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/156126/73648

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name "*mp3*" -exec mv {} $HOME \
```

`find -name "*mp3*"` Encuentra todos los archivos que contengan la cadena `mp3` *en el directorio actual* y sus subdirectorios y por cada uno `-exec mv` ejecuta el comando `mv` sobre el argumento de salida `{}` moviéndolo a tu $HOME.

**Resultado**: mueve todos los mp3 a tu home.

```
find $HOME -name "*.txt" | tr -d " "
```

`find $HOME -name "*.txt"` encuentra todos los archivos con extensión `txt` *en tu directorio home y sus subdirectorios*, y mediante un pipe `|` ejecuta sobre ellos el comando `tr -d` que escribe una linea en donde el argumento es modificado para eliminar de éste una cadena de texto. En este caso la cadena es el espacio `" "`.

**Resultado**, **lista** todos los txt sin espacios en los nombres. No los renombra.

Por qué no sirve hacer `-exec tr -d {}` u otra variante? Bueno, porque exec opera sobre el archivo y `tr` sobre un texto. Al usar el pipe `|` le pasas al comando siguiente la salida de `find` que es sólo el texto del nombre del archivo.