# ¿Qué hacen estos comandos de "find" en Linux?

Tags: linux, búsquedas

No entiendo este comando:

```
find -name "*mp3*" -exec mv {} $HOME \
```

Sé que find está realizando una búsqueda en todos los directorios donde los archivos o directorios que contengan en su nombre mp3 -exec(Creo que sea ejecutable) mv (para mover) {} (No la entiendo muy bien pero es para indicar un patrón) $HOME (hace referencia al directorio /home/) (No tengo idea).

```
find $HOME -name "*.txt" | tr -d " "
```

Parecido al anterior pero con la agregación de tr(no lo entiendo muy bien pero entiendo que lo que pongamos en el argumento 1 "" se remplazara por el argumento 2 "" ej: tr "ax" "bz" remplaza las ax por bz) -d y que el nombre del archivo o directorio termine en .txt

no sé si no se especifica en la comanda find d(directorio) o f(fichero) escoge por defecto uno de los dos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este comando:

```
find -name "*mp3*" -exec mv {} $HOME \
```

Lo que hace es buscar todos los ficheros cuyo nombre contiene "mp3". A continuación, los mueve al directorio "$HOME". Es decir, mueve todos los ficheros al directorio personal del usuario.

Este comando:

```
find $HOME -name "*.txt" | tr -d " "
```

Busca ficheros cuya extensión sea "txt". A continuación, coge el listado y elimina los espacios ("d" en el comando "tr" se refiere a "d"elete, es decir, eliminar). Es decir, quita los espacios de los nombres de los ficheros txt. Pero no sustituye el nombre original, solo lo imprime.

> no sé si no se especifica en la comanda find d(directorio) o f(fichero) escoge por defecto uno de los dos?

No, si no especificas nada, find buscará todos los ficheros, directorios y lo que sea.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación ahora me queda claro.

Answer (score 3):

> `find -name "*mp3*" -exec mv {} $HOME \;`

(He añadido al final un `;` que faltaba)

`-exec` causa que el comando que aparezca detrás de esta opción (hasta donde aparezca un `\;`) sea ejecutado para cada resultado encontrado por find. Dentro del comando puede aparecer `{}` donde queremos que vaya el nombre del fichero.  Así, si uno de los resultados de `find` es `./una/carpeta/archivo.mp3`, se ejecutaría el comando `mv ./una/carpeta/archivo.mp3 $HOME`

> `find $HOME -name "*.txt" | tr -d " "`

En este caso se trata de un find "normal" que simplemente va escribiendo en su salida estándar todos los nombres de fichero que encuentre. La salida estándar de find se redirige mediante una "tubería" o "pipe" (`|`) hacia otro comando, en este caso `tr -d " "`

El comando `tr` va leyendo cadenas de caracteres de su entrada estándar y las va transformando en otras que vuelca en su salida estándar. En este caso las cadenas que reciba serán los nombres de los ficheros hallados por find. La transformación que hace en este caso (`-d " "`) es borrar los espacios en blanco.

Comment: Gracias por expandir un poco más la explicación, muy buena.